# How to prevent site deletion in share point online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, site-deletion

I am looking for the scenario where no user will be able to delete any of the site in SharePoint Online.
How to prevent site deletion in share point online?

Comment: You need to define "site". Is this a Site Collection or a single site in a Site Collection?

Comment: I want to restrict user from deletion of sub-site in SharePoint Online

Answer (score 1):

You can go to the site settings->site permissions, create a permission level which untick “Manage Web site” permission. And then grant the custom permission level to the users who you don’t want to delete the site.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Only site collection administrators have the right to delete the site collections. The best way to prevent users from deleting the site collections is to not provide them the SCA access, instead restrict access to Out of the box groups like owner's, contributors etc.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an [example](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/sharepointdevelopersupport/2012/09/07/how-to-prevent-site-deletion-with-a-custom-event-receiver/) to using WebDeleting event to prevent users delete site collection :

```
public override void WebDeleting(SPWebEventProperties properties)
{
    properties.Status = SPEventReceiverStatus.CancelWithError;
    properties.ErrorMessage = "This site cannot be deleted.";
    properties.Cancel = true;
}
```